# How to get all the data with Promise.all in the useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, use-effect

I have this useEffect hook, that is trying to fetch all the data in one time

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let promises = [];
    data.forEach(item => {
      promises.push(fetch(`https://app.subsocial.network/subid/api/v1/check/${(item.name).toLowerCase()}`))
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(response => response.map(item => item.json()))
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, [data]);
```

But, instead the data I have this in console:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `json()` method returns a promise.

This means that you've used `Promise.all` to wait for all the response promises to resolve, but then you just generate a new bunch of JSON parsing promises instead.

Generate the JSON parsing promises **before** you use `Promise.all`.

i.e.

```
promises.push(
    fetch(`https://app.subsocial.network/subid/api/v1/check/${(item.name).toLowerCase()}`))
    .then(response => response.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to analyze every promise that you get the first `Promise.all`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let promises = [];
  data.forEach((item) => {
    promises.push(
      fetch(
        `https://app.subsocial.network/subid/api/v1/check/${item.name.toLowerCase()}`
      )
    );
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then((responses) => {
      // Take all responses and analyze them with another Promise.all
      return Promise.all(
        responses.map((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
      );
    })
    .then((data) => {
      // Extracted data
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Catched errors
      console.log(error);
    });
}, [data]);
```

In `then` method you are getting all responses, and wrapping them with yet another `Promise.all` so that you can extract from them what they receive.

Comment: Waiting for all the responses to arrive before starting any of the JSON parsing doesn't seem to be an efficient approach to this problem.

Comment: You are correct. Your answer is both cleaner and more efficient.
I will leave my answer to give an alternative for anyone seeking another way if needed. Nice answer @Quentin